# formatting excel cell borders in vb.net

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010

hi I'm pretty new in generating excel reports using visual studio 2010 and I am having trouble finding the right code to put a border on the bottom of the cell. So far I have this code that works fine but it will put all borders.

```
      Wsheet.Cells(9, itemcount + 2).borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
```

Answer (score 4):

Got it! here is what i did.

```
 Wsheet.Cells(9, itemcount + 2).Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Wsheet.Cells(9, itemcount + 2).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
```

also refer to [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692886.aspx) as it is more detailed

Comment: I already tried this but it's giving me an error on `xlEdgeBottom`

Comment: `xlEdgeBottom` is not declared

Comment: you can also try setting/substituting xlEdgeBottom to xlEdgeBottom=9